# 'float' object has no attribute 'shape' in temporal downscaling

Tags: python

I am using NEOPRENE package from github https://github.com/IHCantabria/NEOPRENE

When I

```
# Calculating statistics from the disaggregated daily resample serie and for the period selected from the Input serie
statistics_model_3 = Statistics(hiper_params_cal, time_series = x_series)
statistics_disaggregated = Statistics(hiper_param_cal, time_series = daily_disaggregation)
```

and I got this error code

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[59], line 2
      1 # Calculating statistics from the disaggregated daily resample serie and for the period selected from the Input serie
----> 2 statistics_model_3 = Statistics(hiper_params_cal, time_series = x_series)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\NEOPRENE\NSRP\Statistics.py:89, in Statistics.__init__(self, hiperparams, time_series, file)
     87     raise Exception ('It is not possible to enter two types of data')
     88 if type(time_series)!=type(None):
---> 89     self.statististics_dataframe = statistics_from_serie(statistics_name,Seasonality_str,Seasonality,temporal_resolution, time_series)
     90 elif file != None:
     91     self.statististics_dataframe = statistics_from_file(statistics_name,Seasonality_str,Seasonality,temporal_resolution, file)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\NEOPRENE\NSRP\Statistics.py:57, in statistics_from_serie(statistics_name, Seasonality_str, Seasonality, temporal_resolution, time_series)
     54         Datos = pd.DataFrame (Datos_['Rain'].iloc[pos].values, index = Datos_time_period)
     56         ## We calculate the defined statistics to be adjusted and I enter them in a dataframe.
---> 57     statististics_values = calculate_statistics(Datos,statistics_name, temporal_resolution)
     59     statististics_dataframe.loc[:,str(prii)]=statististics_values
     60 return statististics_dataframe

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\NEOPRENE\NSRP\libs_NSRP.py:56, in calculate_statistics(Data, statistics, temporal_resolution)
     54 if len(aux) <= 1:
     55     l = len(aux) -1
---> 56 Autocorrelation_aux=aux[aux.columns[0]].autocorr(lag=l) 
     57 if np.size(Autocorrelation_aux)>1: Autocorrelation_aux=Autocorrelation_aux[0] 
     58 statistics_values_real.append(Autocorrelation_aux)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:2918, in Series.autocorr(self, lag)
   2875 def autocorr(self, lag: int = 1) -> float:
   2876     """
   2877     Compute the lag-N autocorrelation.
   2878 
   (...)
   2916     nan
   2917     """
-> 2918     return self.corr(self.shift(lag))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:2727, in Series.corr(self, other, method, min_periods)
   2724     return np.nan
   2726 if method in ["pearson", "spearman", "kendall"] or callable(method):
-> 2727     return nanops.nancorr(
   2728         this.values, other.values, method=method, min_periods=min_periods
   2729     )
   2731 raise ValueError(
   2732     "method must be either 'pearson', "
   2733     "'spearman', 'kendall', or a callable, "
   2734     f"'{method}' was supplied"
   2735 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:96, in disallow.__call__.<locals>._f(*args, **kwargs)
     94 try:
     95     with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 96         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     97 except ValueError as e:
     98     # we want to transform an object array
     99     # ValueError message to the more typical TypeError
    100     # e.g. this is normally a disallowed function on
    101     # object arrays that contain strings
    102     if is_object_dtype(args[0]):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:1614, in nancorr(a, b, method, min_periods)
   1611     return np.nan
   1613 f = get_corr_func(method)
-> 1614 return f(a, b)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:1637, in get_corr_func.<locals>.func(a, b)
   1636 def func(a, b):
-> 1637     return np.corrcoef(a, b)[0, 1]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2889, in corrcoef(x, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, dtype)
   2885 if bias is not np._NoValue or ddof is not np._NoValue:
   2886     # 2015-03-15, 1.10
   2887     warnings.warn('bias and ddof have no effect and are deprecated',
   2888                   DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 2889 c = cov(x, y, rowvar, dtype=dtype)
   2890 try:
   2891     d = diag(c)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2724, in cov(m, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, fweights, aweights, dtype)
   2721     else:
   2722         w *= aweights
-> 2724 avg, w_sum = average(X, axis=1, weights=w, returned=True)
   2725 w_sum = w_sum[0]
   2727 # Determine the normalization

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Downscaling\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:557, in average(a, axis, weights, returned, keepdims)
    553     avg = avg_as_array = np.multiply(a, wgt,
    554                       dtype=result_dtype).sum(axis, **keepdims_kw) / scl
    556 if returned:
--> 557     if scl.shape != avg_as_array.shape:
    558         scl = np.broadcast_to(scl, avg_as_array.shape).copy()
    559     return avg, scl

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

how to slove this problem?

I change the package code that

```
def calculate_statistics(Data,statistics,temporal_resolution):
    """ 
    Calculation of the statistics for a given station
    The statistics that can be calculated are:
    statistics=[mean, var_h, autocorr_l_h, fih_h, fiWW_h, fiDD_h, M3_h]
    (l=lag, h=aggregation levels)
    """

    statistics_values_real=list()
    if temporal_resolution=='d':
        t='D'
    elif temporal_resolution=='h':
        t='h'

    for statistic in statistics:

        if 'mean' in statistic:
            statistics_values_real.append(np.nanmean(Data))
        if 'var' in statistic:
            h=int(statistic.split("_",1)[1])
            aux=Data.resample(str(h) + t).sum(); 
            statistics_values_real.append(np.nanvar(aux))
        if 'autocorr' in statistic:
            l=int(statistic.split("_",3)[1])
            h=int(statistic.split("_",3)[2])
            aux=Data.resample(str(h) + t).sum(); 
            if len(aux) <= 1:
            l = len(aux) -1
            Autocorrelation_aux=aux[aux.columns[0]].autocorr(lag=l) 
            if np.size(Autocorrelation_aux)>1: Autocorrelation_aux=Autocorrelation_aux[0] 
            statistics_values_real.append(Autocorrelation_aux)
        if 'fih' in statistic:
            h=int(statistic.split("_",1)[1])
            statistics_values_real.append(fi_h(Data, h, t))
        if 'fiWW' in statistic:
            h=int(statistic.split("_",1)[1])
            statistics_values_real.append(fi_WW(Data, h, t))
        if 'fiDD' in statistic:
            h=int(statistic.split("_",1)[1])
            statistics_values_real.append(fi_DD(Data, h, t))
        if 'M3' in statistic:
            h=int(statistic.split("_",1)[1])
            aux=Data.resample(str(h) + t).sum();
            statistics_values_real.append(sp.stats.moment(aux, moment=3, nan_policy='omit')[0])

    
    return statistics_values_real
```

Do I have to change the package code?
I want to slove this problem.
This code is about daily to hourly downscaling
but I want to do monthly to daily downscaling.
I tried to change the given code to my situation.